# How do I package golang test helper code?

Tags: go, testing

I have some test helper code in my golang library that I want to use when testing in various subpackages. However, I've hit a snag:

```
outer
|
+- test_helpers_test.go
|
+- inner
   |
   +- something.go
   +- something_test.go
```

To use the code in `test_helpers_test.go`, I have to import the outer package. But when I import the outer package from `something_test.go`, it complains "import cycle not allowed in test"

So I tried making a package for the shared test helpers:

```
outer
|
+- test
|  |
|  +- test_helpers_test.go
|
+- inner
   |
   +- something.go
   +- something_test.go
```

And now it complains "no non-test Go files in /home/karl/Projects/outer/test"

I don't want to call it `test_helpers.go` because it's part of my testing code, not my library code. I don't want to ship that code in the library.

How do I solve this?

---

Update: I can work around the issue by creating a `dummy.go` file in the `test` directory, but now there's a new problem: Importing a package DOESN'T import its test code! So now I get: `./something_test.go:12:2: undefined: test.AssertDoesPanic`

Comment: You could call it `test_helpers.go` but have it in a package called `testdata`.

Comment: How would that be different from calling it `test_helpers.go` in a package called `test`?

Comment: Not sure about `test` package names, but `testdata` gets ignored by the go tool.

Comment: I don't want it to be ignored. It contains test code I want to call.

Comment: You can still import it into your test files, although that directory seems to be intended mainly for non go files you can still put go files in it and import it. The ignored-by-the-go-tool might come in handy when you want to run a "project wide" command but you want it to skip the code in testdata, e.g. `go test ./...` or  something like that.

Comment: Either way there's not much you can do about not being able to import code declared in `*_test.go` files. You just have to use a different file name, where you put that file is up to you, as long as you don't violate the no-import-cycle-allowed rule.

Comment: To avoid the test helper code being part of your package's api maybe you could use the `internal` directory, have you considered that?

Comment: That would be no different from having it in the test directory.

Comment: @Karl, yes it would be. Users of your library cannot import your internal packages.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are right that you cannot import test code from another package so your helper functions have to go into proper code files rather than test files.

If it isn't imported from your non-test code then it won't be built into the final binary.

Authors tend to call the package `...test` to indicate it is just test helpers, for instance `httptest` from the standard library or `zaptest` from open source.

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/
https://godoc.org/go.uber.org/zap/zaptest

Answer (score 3):

Following [go issue 8279](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8279), I have seen dummy files added, as in [`tommie/acme-cli` commit 479f8c7](https://github.com/tommie/acme-cli/commit/479f8c7fcafc04a1bdfb2d4a17f209736715120d)

```
outer/outer.go

// +build ignore+
package outer
```

See if that could help here, as a workaround.

---

As commented above, using a test helper code in an [internal package (from Go 1.4+)](https://golang.org/doc/go1.4#internalpackages) is another option, since no client from this project would be able to access said helper. See [design document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e8kOo3r51b2BWtTs_1uADIA5djfXhPT36s6eHVRIvaU/edit).
You can see it used in a [typical Go project layout](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout#internal).