# How to provide reusable test packages to provide test helper functions /structs?

Tags: go

I have the following code for a draft test that I am writing. Within the test function I am creating some json.

I have read about `testdata` for storing test files.

However, I was thinking along the lines of implementing something like a struct that I could implement to provide methods to return reusable fragments of json for use in tests, e.g:

- valid Author json
- invalid Author missing id attribute
- invalid data section, missing id attribute

This way I would not have to copy and paste the same json fragment within each test and would also avoid reading json from disk in `testdata` folder, thus maintain the speed of running tests.

If I add a package containing such an implementation where should it be located so that go excludes it from final executable / release? I am aware that source files ending in `_test.go` are not included. Does go provide something similar like a special test package that contains test helper structs / functions for use within tests?

```golang
func TestUnmarshalAuthor(t *testing.T) {
    sampleData := []byte(`{
        "data": {
            "attributes": {
                "author": "ted",
                "id": "400300"
            },
            "created_on": "2021-01-09T16:39:44.935Z",
            "id": "ad27e265-9605-4b4b-a0e5-3003ea9cc4dc",
            "modified_on": "2021-01-09T16:39:44.935Z",
            "type": "authors"
        },
        "links": {
            "me": "/api/authors/ad27e265-9605-4b4b-a0e5-3003ea9cc4dc"
        }
    }`)

    log.Println("TestUnmarshalAuthor")

    log.Println("Trying to unmarshal the data")
    var data MyAPIResponse
    err := json.Unmarshal(sampleData, &data)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error unmarshalling")
    }

    log.Println(data.Links.Me)
    log.Println(data.Data.Attributes)
    assert.Equal(t, "authors", data.Data.Type)
}
```

**Update**

The accepted answer and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56404355/how-do-i-package-golang-test-helper-code) are considered concise relevant answers to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may put test helpers in a separate package, and if only test files refer (import) to it, it won't be included in the non-test executable binary.

There is no convention to it like test files having a `_test.go` suffix. If a package being built refers to it (be it test or non-test), it will be included. Otherwise it won't.

Also note that you may use a special folder `testdata` to hold static data files for test, the `go` tool ignores it. Quoting from [Command go: Test packages](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Test_packages):

> The go tool will ignore a directory named "testdata", making it available to hold ancillary data needed by the tests.

Comment: Thanks @icza your advice is appreciated :) So if my test package is only referred to by tests it will not be included? Correct?

Comment: @anon_dcs3spp Yes, that's correct.